# getting object properties and methods from multidimensional arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, constructor

I created an `item` constructor along with most of the objects I'd like to create for this project I've been messing with. I then stored all the created items(potions,food,weapons,armor) into a multidimensional array.

The problem I'm having now is display these items in the console.

After the `items` array is created, I've been using `item[subarr1][subarr2].push(item1,item2,item3,item4);` to push the items into their correct arrays, but how do I call properties of the stored objects? I tried, `console.log(items[0][0]);` and `console.log(items[0][0].name);` but the first one returns `[item]` and the other returns `undefined`.

here's the code:

```
//item constructor - defines items parameters
var item = function(name,type,lvl,affect)
{
this.name = name;
this.type = type;
this.lvl = lvl;
this.affect = affect;
}

//create items to be stored in the items Array.
////POTIONS
    //health
    var hP_10       = new item("Health +10","potion",1,"Heals player by +10.");
    var hP_25       = new item("Health +25","potion",1,"Heals player by +25.");
    var hP_50       = new item("Health +50","potion",1,"Heals player by +50.");
    var hP_100      = new item("Health +100","potion",1,"Heals player by +100.");
    //mana
    var mP_10       = new item("Mana +10","potion",1,"Refills Mana by +10.");
    var mP_25       = new item("Mana +25","potion",1,"Refills Mana by +25.");
    var mP_50       = new item("Mana +50","potion",1,"Refills Mana by +50.");
    var mP_100      = new item("Mana +100","potion",1,"Refills Mana by +100."); 
    //energy
    var eP_10       = new item("Energy +10","potion",1,"Refills Energy by +10.");
    var eP_25       = new item("Energy +25","potion",1,"Refills Energy by +25.");
    var eP_50       = new item("Energy +50","potion",1,"Refills Energy by +50.");
    var eP_100      = new item("Energy +100","potion",1,"Refills Energy by +100."); 
////
////FOOD
    //health - fruits
    var apple       = new item("Apple","food",1,"Heals player by +10.");
    var orange      = new item("Orange","food",1,"Heals player by +25.");
    var banana      = new item("Banana","food",1,"Heals player by +50.");
    var pear        = new item("Pear","food",1,"Heals player by +100.");
    //mana - vegetables 
    var carrot      = new item("Carrot","food",1,"Refills Mana by +10.");
    var celery      = new item("Celery","food",1,"Refills Mana by +25.");
    var broccoli    = new item("Broccoli","food",1,"Refills Mana by +50.");
    var onion       = new item("Onion","food",1,"Refills Mana by +100.");
    //energy - snacks
    var cupcake     = new item("Cupcake","food",1,"Refills Energy by +10.");
    var cookie      = new item("Cookie","food",1,"Refills Energy by +25.");
    var brownie     = new item("Brownie","food",1,"Refills Energy by +50.");
    var rice_crispy = new item("Rice Crispy","food",1,"Refills Energy by +100.");
////
////BOOSTERS
    var hB_10       = new item("Health +10","potion",1,"Adds +10 to player Health.");
    var hB_25       = new item("Health +25","potion",1,"Adds +25 to player Health.");
    var hB_50       = new item("Health +50","potion",1,"Adds +50 to player Health.");
    var hB_100      = new item("Health +100","potion",1,"Adds +100 to player Health.");
    //mana
    var mB_10       = new item("Mana +10","potion",1,"Adds +10 to player Mana.");
    var mB_25       = new item("Mana +25","potion",1,"Adds +25 to player Mana.");
    var mB_50       = new item("Mana +50","potion",1,"Adds +50 to player Mana.");
    var mB_100      = new item("Mana +100","potion",1,"Adds +100 to player Mana."); 
    //energy
    var eB_10       = new item("Mana +10","potion",1,"Adds +10 to player Mana.");
    var eB_25       = new item("Mana +25","potion",1,"Adds +25 to player Mana.");
    var eB_50       = new item("Mana +50","potion",1,"Adds +50 to player Mana.");
    var eB_100      = new item("Mana +100","potion",1,"Adds +100 to player Mana.");
////
////WEAPONS
    //staff

    //bow

    //sword

    //dagger
////
////ARMOR
    //helm

    //shoulders

    //bracers

    //chest

    //legs

    //boots
////
//

//store all items in items Array
/*
items = list ALL items.
items[0] = potions
items[0][0] = potions -> health
items[1] = food
items[1][0] = food -> health
items[2] = boosters
items[2][0] = boosters -> health
items[3] = weapons
items[3][0] = weapons -> staff
items[4] = armor
items[4][0] = armor -> helm
*/
var items = 
[
//POTIONS
[
    //health
    [],
    //mana
    [],
    //energy
    [],
],
//FOOD
[
    //health
    [],
    //mana
    [],
    //energy
    []
],
//BOOSTERS
[
    //health
    [],
    //mana
    [],
    //energy
    []
],
//WEAPONS
[
    //staff
    [],
    //bow
    [],
    //sword
    [],
    //dagger
    []
],
//ARMOR
[
    //helm
    [],
    //shoulders
    [],
    //bracer's
    [],
    //chest
    [],
    //legs
    [],
    //boots
    []
]
];
//push health potions
//items -> potions -> health
items[0][0].push(hP_10,hP_25,hP_50,hP_100);
console.log(items[0][0]);
```

The only time it displays the way i'd like it to is if I do this `items[0][0].push(hP_10.name)`, but obviously that doesn't store the whole object.

Any tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of indexed data that you are  referencing with an array. I would turn items into an object so as items is more readable like so.

```
var items = 
{
    "potions":{},
    "food":{"cupcake":cupcake,"cookie":cookie,"brownie":brownie,"rice_crispy":rice_crispy},
    "boosters":{},
    "weapons":{},
    "armor":{}
};
console.log(items);
console.log(items.food.cupcake.affect);
```

Comment: This helps a TON! Just out of curiosity then, what kind of complex data sets are good for multidimensional arrays when turning something into an object makes the data so much more readable?

Comment: I would look at mysql. Create a table name of `items` then add the columns from the arguments in your item function  `name,type,lvl,affect`. Add the data. then, when the data is needed, use an ajax call to a php mysql query and use the response data as a json object.

Comment: That comment answered so many questions I've had. Thanks for the info man! :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake. when calling for object properties and methods I was using `console.log(items[0][0].name)` which was really calling for the name of the sub array.

The correct syntax is `console.log(items[0][0][0].name)` which will give you the name of the first object stored in the first subarray in the first array of `items`.